# How do I force Android Studio to do a full build every time?

Tags: android, rebuild

I recently went from Android Studio 3.0 to 2022.  Of course upgrading everything was a nightmare, but it finally got all the kinks worked out except one. In 3.0, when I used to hit the play button to run my app on my device, all changes I made were immediately reflected along with all errors and Gradle changes. Tonight I just wasted 3 hours because I was updating code in an adapter and was simply trying to change a text element of a chart object. I kept trying different things and the chart's description label element wouldn't change text or color.  I thought I was coding something wrong. I finally did a rebuild and the changes took place.   How do I go back to hitting the play button and doing a full rebuild each time exactly how 3.0 was?  I can't afford to have Google "save me time" anymore.

I've looked around to turn off some sort of auto run feature, but that option isn't there any longer and I'm not sure what the details are regarding what Studio is doing now.